# Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{2d637e8 V.E...... R....... 0,0-768,293} that was originally added here

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I am getting window leaked error. I am trying to show a dialog with YES and NO button.If user clicks NO button then trying to close the app by calling finish() method. Problem here is that finish() method is called without showing the  dialog. I am unable to understand why dialog isn't showing.

```
public class LoadingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private String TAG = LoadingActivity.class.getSimpleName();
        private Boolean isConnected;
        private Boolean retry;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);
            Log.d(TAG,"onCreate()");

            retry = false;
            do{
               // NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                isConnected = MiscService.isConnectedToInternet(this);
                if(!isConnected) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"Internet Connection: " + isConnected);

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setMessage("No Internet Connection Available. Do you want to try again?");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            retry = true;
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            retry = false;
                        }
                    });

                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
            }while(retry);

            if(!isConnected ){
                //Exit the application
                Log.i(TAG,"Closing App...");
                finish();
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void finish() {
            super.finish();
        }
    }
```

stacktrace...

```
06-03 09:43:35.329 21582-21582/com.example.andonsystem W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
06-03 09:43:35.340 21582-21582/com.example.andonsystem D/LoadingActivity: onCreate()
06-03 09:43:35.342 21582-21582/com.example.andonsystem I/LoadingActivity: Internet Connection: false
06-03 09:43:35.402 21582-21627/com.example.andonsystem D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                                         [ 06-03 09:43:35.411 21582:21582 D/         ]
                                                                         HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xed760550, tid 21582
06-03 09:43:35.429 21582-21582/com.example.andonsystem I/LoadingActivity: Closing App...

                                                                          [ 06-03 09:43:35.448  3060: 3781 D/         ]
                                                                          HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xdd360300, tid 3781
06-03 09:43:35.937 21582-21627/com.example.andonsystem D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
06-03 09:43:35.939 21582-21627/com.example.andonsystem D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
06-03 09:43:35.980 21582-21627/com.example.andonsystem D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so

                                                                 [ 06-03 09:43:36.007 21582:21627 D/         ]
                                                                 HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xed760f40, tid 21627
06-03 09:43:36.053 21582-21627/com.example.andonsystem I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-03 09:43:36.185 21582-21627/com.example.andonsystem W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-03 09:43:36.185 21582-21627/com.example.andonsystem W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xf04efda0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-03 09:43:36.673 21582-21582/com.example.andonsystem E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.andonsystem.LoadingActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{63c85d2 V.E...... R....... 0,0-768,293} that was originally added here
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:368)
                                                                            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:299)
                                                                            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                                                                            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:319)
                                                                            at com.example.andonsystem.LoadingActivity.onCreate(LoadingActivity.java:72)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
06-03 09:43:36.708 21582-21627/com.example.andonsystem E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xeb1ab7a0
```

Updated Code...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);
        Log.d(TAG,"onCreate()");

        //retry = false;


        isConnected = MiscService.isConnectedToInternet(this);
        if(!isConnected) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Internet Connection: " + isConnected);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("No Internet Connection Available. Do you want to try again?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"Closing App...");
                    finish();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
```

Thanks for help in advance...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the time when you are trying  to show your dialog, the activity is getting destroyed since you called `finish()`. This leads to the window leakage and is apparent from the logs you attached.

You are doing both the job when the same condition turns true -

```
 if(!isConnected)
```

You should do that in different conditions otherwise what is the point in showing the dialog and finishing the activity at the same time. The user will never be able to see the dialog.

Comment: yes..I have same condition for both but I am showing dialog before and then if user has clicked No then second if should come in effect and close the app,since, Statements are executed line by line . If build of dialog takes on different thread then this output should come..is it the case. Dialog build is taking place on different thread

Comment: When you show the dialog, it doesn't means that it will halt the execution of the statements after that. So your code will be executed sequentially and the dialog will not stop it.

Comment: No, it takes place on UI thread only but it doesn't waits for user input.

Comment: I changed my logic. I called finish() method inside onClick listener of negativeButton. But the problem is that dialog is never shown in my app. Why is dialog not showing

Comment: I have posted the updated code logic.Please review it  and Thanks for your time...

Comment: Is this log `Log.i(TAG,"Internet Connection: " + isConnected);` printed ?

Comment: yes and it is false. I am checking for false case only.

Comment: My main intention is to check for internet connectivity. If it is false, Show alert dialog asking user if he wants to try again. If yes check again if connection is enabled and if no close the app. I would appreciate your help if could provide any solution for this.

Comment: Are you still getting the same error or is there some other issue?

Comment: No I am not getting the error. that was off course because the activity being closed before calling dailog.show() method.  But dailog is never shown even after changing the logic

Comment: From the posted updated code, it doesn't seems there is any issue. Try posting complete `onCreate() `method.

Comment: I think I have recognized the problem. I was starting another activity in same UI thread and so next activity was started before dialog can be shown.  Now I am starting another activity in else condition. Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution.  AlertDialog is created parallely and it doesn't halt the UI thread. Therefore call to finish()  was made before dialog.show()  method was called and giving memory leak error.  So I now made the call inside onClickListener of negative button and problem was gone. 
Second problem that dialog was not showing because I was starting another activity on the same UI thread. So next activity was started before dialog can be shown. Now I start activity if isConnected is true. So now dialog has all the time to be shown